# How to Add Span tag to text in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Greetings to all friends of WordPress and Code ❤️,
This i my first post here so i hope i do it in a good way,)

**How can add a span tag to a text in WordPress in one click?**

What I am intending to achieve is the addition of a button to the Gutenberg editor toolbar. This button, once clicked, should surround the selected text with a tag `<span data-no-translation=""><span>`. I have tried various approaches using the WordPress block API, but the resulting outcome is not what I expected. All I manage to achieve is the visibility of the `no translate` button.

After several attempts, the button does not function as anticipated. Either it does nothing at all, or it simply adds the tag without the selected content, or I have something better: `<span class="no-translation">test<span>`.

However, what I want is: `<span data-no-translation="">test<span>`

Below is the JavaScript code that I utilized for my customized button:

```
(function (wp) {
    var MyCustomButton = function (props) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.blockEditor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
                icon: 'editor-code',
                title: 'No Translate',
                onClick: function () {
                    props.onChange(wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        { type: 'my-plugin/my-custom-button' }
                    ));
                },
                isActive: props.isActive,
            }
        );
    }
    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-plugin/my-custom-button', {
            title: 'No Translate',
            tagName: 'span',
            className: 'no-translation',
            attributes: {
                'data-no-translation': 'true'
            },
            edit: MyCustomButton,
        }
    );
})(window.wp);
```

this code in my functions.php file

```
function mon_plugin_gutenberg() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'mon-plugin-gutenberg',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mon-plugin-gutenberg.js',
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom', 'wp-editor', 'wp-rich-text' ),
        filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/mon-plugin-gutenberg.js' )
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'mon_plugin_gutenberg' );
```

I am sure it is a minor error in my code or a configuration issue, but I am unable to find the solution. If anyone could lend me a hand in resolving this issue, I would be immensely grateful.

I use this attribute to avoid translating certain links or texts, for instance for my page with TranslatePress plugin which automatically changes/translates the URLs if it is an internal URL https://translatepress.com/

For instance I added a link to my homepage (https://wikihhc.com/) in the content of my page: https://wikihhc.com/guide/hhc/ and if I don’t add  `<span data-no-translation=””>`  by going through “edit in HTML”, the link is no longer on the homepage but on https://wikihhc.com/es/

for the page translated into Spanish, for instance:https://wikihhc.com/es/guia/hhc/

In most cases this is what I want but in this particular example, no.)